# why is pd.get_dummies returning Boolean values instead of the binaries of 0 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I don't know why my One-Hot encoding code; "pd.get_dummies" is returning Boolean values instead of the binaries of 0 1
`df = pd.get_dummies(df)`

after writing the following line of code; `df = pd.get_dummies(df)`
and also tried; `df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['column_a', 'column_b', 'column_c'])`
the returning values of both were booleans True and False instead of 0 and 1

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `pd.get_dummies` return Boolean, try  :

```py
df = pd.get_dummies(df, dtype=int)
```

Comment: X = pd.get_dummies(X, dtype='int')
I did it after the split
Thanks a lot